# How to access nested JSON in brackets in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, parsing

I have a JSON response which is in brackets and I struggle to access the inner fields e.g. display_name with Swift. How can I do that?

```
Optional(["result": {
user =     {
    "display_name" = "Max Test";
    email = "test.max@gmail.com";
    "fb_id" = 10209982554704497;
    roles =         (
        stu
    );
    schools = "<null>";
};
}])
```

The code I used to access the JSON:

```
 self.restApi.getProfileDetails() {responseObject, error in

        //parse down the first layer of array
        let response = responseObject as? [String:AnyObject]
        print("response object when MyDetailsController opened")
        print(response)

        let result = response!["result"]  as? [AnyObject]
        print("result object")
        print(result)

        //parse down the second layer of JSON object
        if let result = response!["result"]  as? [AnyObject] {

            print("result object when MyDetailsController opened")
            // work with the content of "result", for example:
            if let user = result[0] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                print(user)

                let displayName = user["display_name"]
                print("displayName")
                print(displayName)

             }
    }
```

It seems that I address the result in the wrong way as it is always nil:

The console output:

```
result object
nil
```

Comment: try to use  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseObject!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

Comment: **response!["result"]  as? [AnyObject]** - this is an issue. The object is not a [AnyObject], it's a Dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response result is `dictionary` not `array`, try to get like this

```
let result = response!["result"]  as? [String:AnyObject]
```

Comment: Yes this helped. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1-Get the result object from response 
2-Get the user object from result object 
3-Get the user info as String from user object .

```
let response = responseObject as? [String: AnyObject]
let result = response!["result"]  as? [String: AnyObject]

if let user = result!["user"]  as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let displayName = user["display_name"] as? String
        let email = user["email"] as? String
}
```