# Accessing nested JSON data

Tags: json, macos, swift3

I'm using [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) to help me achieve asynchronous HTTP requests in my osx application. My HTTP requests are modeled as a stream that returns an `Observable<Any?>`. The `Any?` value that is returned is a jsonObject created from the data received in the HTTP response:

```
let data = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)    
return Observable.just(data)
```

After making an HTTP request, I then subscribe to the stream, waiting for the next value to arrive. After it arrives, I save the data as a `[String: Any]` before proceeding:

```
let onNextSubscription = httpResponse?.subscribe(onNext: { data in
    if let data = data as? [String: Any] {
        print(data)
        ...
    }
}
```

In this scenario, I am evaluating a CheckVersion method in my application to ensure that it is of a version that is currently supported. To accomplish this, I call out to a service that sends back JSON data regarding which versions of the application are currently supported and where to find them on the web if the evaluation fails. I then use data from the response in conjunction with data from within the app to evaluate whether or not the application is supported and proceed accordingly. That is, I will compare the "minVersion" value from the JSON data with the app's version to determine the result of the CheckVersion method.

The data I receive from the HTTP response is:

```
["status": 0, "result": {
    "minVersion":"1.7.0",
    "currVersion":"2.0.0",
    "urls":{
        "2.0.0":"/downloads/app.2.0.0.exe",
        "1.9.0":"/downloads/app.1.9.0.exe",
        "1.8.0":"/downloads/app.1.8.0.exe",
        "1.7.0":"/downloads/app.1.7.0.exe",
    }
}]
```

My next step is to retrieve the "minVersion" value from the data, so I continue within the same `if {...}` block shown above:

```
let result = data["result"] as? [String: Any]
print(result)

let minVersion = result["minVersion"] as? String
print(minVersion)

...
```

What I expect to be able to do is access the value as `result["minVersion]` before executing my version comparison logic; however, I am unable to, because `data["result"] == nil` after it is downcast to `[String: Any]`.

When `data["result"]` is forcibly downcast to `[String: Any]`, I receive the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDictionary'.

I'm not sure why this is going on as other posts I've seen around the web have shown that this is a normal means of accessing nested JSON data, although maybe I'm missing something.

My best guess is that it has to do with the fact that `result["urls"]` values contains a jsonObject of its own, while `result`'s other values are simply strings.

Here are some of documents that I referenced while modeling my code:

1. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37
2. [How to access nested JSON in brackets in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743156/how-to-access-nested-json-in-brackets-in-swift)

I'm a C# .NET developer by trade, and this is my first foray into OS X and Swift world, so thanks in advance for the help and for bearing with me on this!

**Edit:** Here is the result of print(data["result"]):

```
Optional({
    "minVersion":"1.7.0",
    "currVersion":"2.0.0",
    "urls":{
        "2.0.0":"/downloads/app.2.0.0.exe",
        "1.9.0":"/downloads/app.1.9.0.exe",
        "1.8.0":"/downloads/app.1.8.0.exe",
        "1.7.0":"/downloads/app.1.7.0.exe",
    }
})
```

**Edit:** As per Dan's request, I tried the method outlined in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary).

```
let subNext = httpResponse?.subscribe(onNext: { data in
    if let data = data as? [String: Any] {
        print(data)

        let result = self.convertToDictionary(text: data["result"] as! String)
        print(result)
    }
})
```

The result is:

```
Optional(["currVersion": 2.0.0, "urls": {
    "1.7.0" = "/downloads/app.1.7.0.exe",
    "1.8.0" = "/downloads/app.1.8.0.exe",
    "1.9.0" = "/downloads/app.1.9.0.exe",
    "2.0.0" = "/downloads/app.2.0.0.exe",
}, "minVersion": 1.7.0])
```

**Final Edit**

Thanks to Rob and Dan in the comments, I was able to solve my problem. It was essentially the same as shown in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary)

I'll go ahead and flag this one as a duplicate.

Comment: The error message is telling you the `data["result"]` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that much. I know that I need to be able to take that string and format it into a `[String: Any]` so that I can take advantage of the key-value pairs stored within. I'm just not sure what the right approach is in trying to accomplish that.

Comment: Well if the string is a json string then see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary

Comment: Interestingly enough, `print(JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(data))` returned `true` while `print(JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(data["result"]))` returned `false`. 
Then `let result = data["result"] as! [String: AnyObject]` returned the same error as before, I assume because it has been shown that data["result"] is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: So it looks like I need to determine why `data["result"]` is not valid JSON and find out how to deal with it.

Comment: That's not what `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject` is for.  Did you try the code from the answer in the question I linked?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, that is what is being shown in the console.

Comment: @Dan: I tried the code solution you recommended. I got an error: "The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format."

Comment: @Rob: Our platform uses services that are written in C#. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Can you do a `print(data["result"])` and edit the output into your question?

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for the response. I'll definitely look into this.

Comment: @Dan: I've updated the question as you asked.

Comment: @ncats I don't see where you've shown the result of `print(data["result"])`.  Your attempt to try the method I linked is also wrong, you need to properly unwrap `data["result"]` as a string.  `String(describing:)` won't produce a valid json string.

Comment: @Dan: Sorry about that. How does it look now?

Comment: @Rob: Thank you for spotting that mistake! This seems to have produced a value. I'll edit my question to show the true response.

Comment: Thanks, anyway for the help, @Rob. I greatly appreciate the time you spent helping me out.

Comment: In your final edit, you have an optional dictionary. You can now unwrap that, e.g. `if let result = self.convertToDictionary(text: data["result"] as! String), let minVersion = result["minVersion"] as? String { print(minVersion) }`.

Comment: @Dan: I've edited my question to show the true response after Rob pointed out a mistake I made.

Comment: This is wonderful. I've got it working. Thank you both for all your help!